# Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id in a managed package procedure

Tags: apex, trigger, cpq

I have added a changing Opportunity owner logic inside Opportunity before triggers. And this is causing issue in a managed package procedure when I amend a contract in Salesforce cpq package. The error message is: 
Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.

However, if I just create this record by commenting out the relevant code in my trigger and then add the logic back, in a non-out-of-box scenario, the trigger works perfectly fine with that profile. I have also tried to add without sharing key words which doesn't seem to work as well.

I have tried to use future methods but since I need to modify the trigger related records it has to be in the before trigger without using DML. So I am really running out of option here. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Any idea which specific lookup is throwing the access error? My first guess would be that if the new owner doesn't actually have access to the Account the Opportunity belongs to, it'd toss this error.

Comment: @CharlesT I tried the same opportunity with the same owner outside the cpq button and it just work fine. So it shouldn't be that issue

Comment: Hmm. Well ultimately the package developer is going to be the one who knows what's really happening. Can CPQ Support help you debug this? Presumably this means your trigger is resulting in some sort of invalid combination of ownerships by the time the DML transaction is committed.